# Laravel login with username instead of email

Tags: php, laravel

How can I make login with username, instead of email?

It's my login.blade.php

```
@extends('layouts.main')
@section('errors')
@if (count($errors) > 0)
    <div class="alert alert-danger">
        <ul>
            @foreach ($errors->all() as $error)
                <li>{{ $error }}</li>
            @endforeach
        </ul>
    </div>
@endif
@section('content')
<form method="POST" action="/auth/login">
    {!! csrf_field() !!}

    <div>
        Email
        <input type="email" name="email" value="{{ old('email') }}">
    </div>

    <div>
        Password
        <input type="password" name="password" id="password">
    </div>

    <div>
        <input type="checkbox" name="remember"> Remember Me
    </div>

    <div>
        <button type="submit">Login</button>
    </div>
</form>
</body>
@stop
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You change email to username in you form

```
<form method="POST" action="/auth/login">
    {!! csrf_field() !!}

    <div>
        Email
        <input type="text" name="username" value="{{ old('username') }}">
    </div>

    <div>
        Password
        <input type="password" name="password" id="password">
    </div>

    <div>
        <input type="checkbox" name="remember"> Remember Me
    </div>

    <div>
        <button type="submit">Login</button>
    </div>
</form>
```

and in you AuthenticatesAndRegisterUsers.php you change email to username also.

```
public function postLogin(Request $request)
    {
        $this->validate($request, [
            'username' => 'required', 'password' => 'required',
        ]);

        $credentials = $request->only('username', 'password');

        if ($this->auth->attempt($credentials, $request->has('remember')))
        {
            return redirect()->intended($this->redirectPath());
        }

        return redirect($this->loginPath())
                    ->withInput($request->only('username', 'remember'))
                    ->withErrors([
                        'username' => $this->getFailedLoginMessage(),
                    ]);
    }
```

Comment: this file. c:\myadmin\htdocs\laravel\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\AuthenticatesAndRegistersUsers.php

Comment: `FatalErrorException in AuthenticatesUsers.php line 51:
Access to undeclared static property: Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth::$this` 51line: `if (Auth::$this->auth->attempt($credentials, $request->has('remember'))) {`

Comment: does method postLogin already exists? in AuthenticatesUser.php file. what version of Laravel are you using. Laravel 5 or 5.1. in my case i'm using laravel 5.0 and the file is named AuthenticatesAndRegistersUsers.php

Comment: May be you need to import the Auth class.

Answer (score 1):

By default, [Laravel uses the email field for authentication](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/authentication). If you would like to customize this, you may define a username method on your LoginController:

```
public function username()
{
    return 'username';
}
```